# ViewHolder in recyclerView register visible view position and not absolute view position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

**Intended behaviour:**

Hello I am using a recyclerView to display a grid of images, loaded from a List<> saved in the ViewAdapter. 
When the user clicks an image a new fragment is created and is given as argument the corresponding item in the List<>. I do this with this code

```
private class ShowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
//holder code...

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int itemPosition = mRecyclerView.indexOfChild(view);

            Fragment newDetail = DetailFragment.newInstance(mShowAdapter.getList().get(itemPosition));
            //launch Fragment
        }
    }
```

This: `mShowAdapter.getList().get(itemPosition)` return the item to be passed from the List<>. This works fine for any item in the view but only if i DON'T scroll down.

**The bug:**

When I scroll down a few pages and I click an item, the wrong item is fetched from the list. For example let's say i click the first visible item after scrolling a few pages. The item retrieved form the list is actually the first item in the List<> and not the 27th.

This happens because the recyclerView is registering the click position relative to the VISIBLE items. Doesn't matter how far down I scroll, if I click the third visible item it is the same thing as if I hit the third absolute item at the top.

How can I fix this so that the correct item is retrieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
int itemPosition = getAdapterPosition ();
```

Comment: Was just about to edit the question. Using`int itemPosition= MyViewHolder.this.getAdapterPosition();` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to set onclick listener in onBindViewHolder().